# MySQL "default" result

Tags: mysql, data-structures

I have a MySQL table like

```
id    |  text   |  category   |   active
```

I select a random line with

```
SELECT id, text 
FROM table
WHERE category = [category id] AND active = 1 
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

Some times this would return no results (e.g. if there is no active row in a specific category). What I need to do in that case is to return a "default" row.

My question is: what is the most efficient way to do this? Should I just create an identical table but just with the default rows, which I would query if the above query gives no results? Or should I add the default rows in the same table? And how would you query it?

Any suggestion is welcome!

**EDIT**
A few updates to the question:

1. I am excluding the possibility of generating the default text in PHP, as I want it to be customizable, without having to go and change the code.
2. There will be a default row per category

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the default value you want? The 1st id in the table?

```
SELECT id, text
FROM (  SELECT id, categori, active, text, 0 AS prio
        FROM table WHERE category = [category id] AND active = 1 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT id, categori, active, text, 1
        FROM table
        ORDER BY id ASC
        LIMIT 1) AS h
ORDER BY prio, RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

If you wish for a certain default value, add a ENUM column called `default('TRUE', 'FALSE')`:

```
SELECT id, text
FROM (  SELECT id, categori, active, text, 0 AS prio
        FROM table WHERE category = [category id] AND active = 1 AND default = 'FALSE'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT id, categori, active, text, 1
        FROM table
        WHERE category = [category id] AND default = 'TRUE'
        ORDER BY id ASC
        LIMIT 1) AS h
ORDER BY prio, RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

**Easier one:**

```
SELECT id, text
FROM table
WHERE category = [category id] AND (active = 1 OR default = 'TRUE')
ORDER BY (default = 'FALSE') DESC, RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

**Explanation:**
Basicly this query fetches all the rows you count on to get, and combine it with a default row. They got a prio value each, which you order them in before doing `RAND()`. The thing remaining is how you wish to store your default rows.

Comment: Hmmm this seems to be going towards what I need

Comment: I've added a bit of explanation aswell. Let me know if you need more examples.

Comment: been a bit busy, will try that tonight

Comment: Works, although there is no need to add the priority flag, as you already have the default column. Actually, just ordering by `prio, RAND()` (without using the `UNION`) seems to be sufficient.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. I just built on a query which became a bit more complex, and could be redone instead. I inserted a 3rd query which hopefully represents the answer better for your case.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT id, text 
FROM table
WHERE (category = [category id] AND active = 1 ) 
    OR ((DEFAULT CONDITION) AND NOT((category = [category id] AND active = 1 )))
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be able to draw the default value by random, and not only if 1st conditions aren't met?

Comment: I am not sure I understand this query... I don't have a default condition, I have a default result. Am I missing something?

Comment: Don't take the `DEFAULT CONDITION` literal. It's an example that you could filter the row by a certain condition which would fetch your default row.

Comment: Ok, but then if I order by `rand()` I am not certain that I will get the default one only if the first condition is not met

Comment: edit: Now you will not get the default row when there are real rows. And 'DEFAULT CONDITION' is (as Robin said) any condition that matches a row you want as default.

Comment: I will test that, but isn't `ORDER BY RAND` executed after retreiving all of the rows that match the `WHERE` clause? In that case if there are rows you would still select the default one and you may have it as first results due to the ordering.

Answer (score 0):

How do you mean a "default row"? I'm not really sure if I get what you mean. But if you're saying you want to output something anyway -even though there aren't any results-, I would just do that programmatically.

Just check if you have a result set with data, if not, output something through the script.

Comment: I added a comment on that in the question

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what language you're using, you could just see how many rows were returned:

```
// php

$res = mysql_query("...");

if( mysql_num_rows($res) < 1 )
{
  // no result
}
else
{
  // do something
}
```

Comment: See the last sentence in the question. The default results need to be customizable